# Binary search program keeps getting max recursion depth error

Tags: python

```
def binary_search(lst,target,ub,lb):
    mid=(ub+lb)/2
    if target==lst[mid]:
        return target
    elif target>lst[mid]:
        mid =(mid+ub)/2
        return binary_search(lst,target,ub,mid)
    elif target<lst[mid]:
        mid =(mid+lb)/2
        return binary_search(lst,target,mid,lb)
    elif ub<lb:
        return 'No target value found'
    else:
        return mid
```

Answer (score 0):

`ub<lb` is the base condition for this recursion. So, that has to be checked first.

```
def binary_search(lst,target,ub,lb):
    mid=(ub+lb)/2
    if ub<lb:
        return 'No target value found'
    elif target==lst[mid]:
        return target
    elif target>lst[mid]:
        mid =(mid+ub)/2
        return binary_search(lst,target,ub,mid)
    elif target<lst[mid]:
        mid =(mid+lb)/2
        return binary_search(lst,target,mid,lb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the algorithm without the recursion, then it will not reach the maximum recursion depth:

```
def binary_search(lst,target,ub,lb):
    mid=(ub+lb) // 2
    while target != lst[mid]:
        if target > lst[mid]:
            lb =(mid+ub) // 2
        if target < lst[mid]:
            ub =(mid+lb) // 2
        if ub<lb:
            return 'No target value found'
        mid=(ub+lb) // 2
    return mid
```

Two notes:

1º. You have a bug in the boundary update, both boundaries updates skip half of the items.

2º. The division operator `/` returns a float on python 3, you want to use floor division `//`

```
>> 3/5
0.6
>> 3//5
0
```